# partially format a string with either old or new style formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to partially format a string in python with some named arguments, but leave any unused or unmatched format specifiers unchanged.  For example:

```
"{} {} {arg1}".format(arg1="hi")
prints:
"{} {} hi"
```

rather than throwing an IndexError. Or:

```
"%d %d %(arg1)s" % {'arg1': "hi"}
prints
"%d %d hi"
```

rather than throwing a TypeError.

Is there some partially hidden corner of the format module that does this (or a option to pass into format())?

I don't have the luxury of creating the format strings myself, they are provided, but I can specify certain fields to be replaced before it is passed upstream. For example, I can specify that if there is one or more %(arg1)s in the string, I will replace it with "hi" before I pass it upstream.

Comment: other then using `"%%d %%d %(arg1)s" % {'arg1': "hi"}` there is no built in way.